# Problema con sql developer

Tags: oracle-11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

He instalado la base de datos de oracle 11g express y pretende acceder a ella desde el sql developer pero a la hora establecer la conexion me da el siguiente error, he estado buscando por internet pero no me aclaro.

Estado: Fallo:Fallo de la prueba: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12528, TNS:listener: all appropriate instances are blocking new connections

```
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                03-DIC-2017 10:34:13
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 46 min. 8 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\TOSHIBA-JOSE\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=TOSHIBA-JOSE)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 3 handler(s) for this service...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "xe" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status BLOCKED, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Tue Dec 05 18:06:36 2017
Starting ORACLE instance (normal)
LICENSE_MAX_SESSION = 0
LICENSE_SESSIONS_WARNING = 0
Picked latch-free SCN scheme 3
Using LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_1 parameter default value as USE_DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST
Autotune of undo retention is turned on. 
IMODE=BR
ILAT =18
LICENSE_MAX_USERS = 0
SYS auditing is disabled
Starting up:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production.
Using parameter settings in server-side pfile C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\PRODUCT\11.2.0\SERVER\DATABASE\INITXE.ORA
System parameters with non-default values:
  sessions                 = 172
  spfile                   = "C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\PRODUCT\11.2.0\SERVER\DBS\SPFILEXE.ORA"
  memory_target            = 1G
  control_files            = "C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\ORADATA\XE\CONTROL.DBF"
  compatible               = "11.2.0.0.0"
  db_recovery_file_dest    = "C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\fast_recovery_area"
  db_recovery_file_dest_size= 10G
  undo_management          = "AUTO"
  undo_tablespace          = "UNDOTBS1"
  remote_login_passwordfile= "EXCLUSIVE"
  dispatchers              = "(PROTOCOL=TCP) (SERVICE=XEXDB)"
  shared_servers           = 4
  job_queue_processes      = 4
  audit_file_dest          = "C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\ADMIN\XE\ADUMP"
  db_name                  = "XE"
  open_cursors             = 300
  diagnostic_dest          = "C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE"
Tue Dec 05 18:06:41 2017
PMON started with pid=2, OS id=1448 
Tue Dec 05 18:06:41 2017
PSP0 started with pid=3, OS id=12468 
Tue Dec 05 18:06:42 2017
VKTM started with pid=4, OS id=16752 at elevated priority
Tue Dec 05 18:06:42 2017
GEN0 started with pid=5, OS id=7136 
Tue Dec 05 18:06:42 2017
DIAG started with pid=6, OS id=3752 
Tue Dec 05 18:06:42 2017
DBRM started with pid=7, OS id=8528 
Tue Dec 05 18:06:42 2017
DIA0 started with pid=8, OS id=13212 
VKTM running at (10)millisec precision with DBRM quantum (100)ms
Time drift detected. Please check VKTM trace file for more details.
Tue Dec 05 18:06:42 2017
MMAN started with pid=9, OS id=11924 
Tue Dec 05 18:06:43 2017
DBW0 started with pid=10, OS id=11428 
Tue Dec 05 18:06:43 2017
LGWR started with pid=11, OS id=15780 
Tue Dec 05 18:06:43 2017
CKPT started with pid=12, OS id=15056 
Tue Dec 05 18:06:43 2017
SMON started with pid=13, OS id=8820 
Tue Dec 05 18:06:43 2017
RECO started with pid=14, OS id=10092 
Tue Dec 05 18:06:43 2017
MMON started with pid=15, OS id=9948 
Tue Dec 05 18:06:43 2017
MMNL started with pid=16, OS id=6100 
starting up 1 dispatcher(s) for network address '(ADDRESS=(PARTIAL=YES)(PROTOCOL=TCP))'...
starting up 4 shared server(s) ...
ORACLE_BASE from environment = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle
Tue Dec 05 18:06:44 2017
ALTER DATABASE   MOUNT
ORA-00210: cannot open the specified control file
ORA-00202: control file: 'C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\ORADATA\XE\CONTROL.DBF'
ORA-27041: unable to open file
OSD-04002: unable to open file
O/S-Error: (OS 2) El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.
ORA-205 signalled during: ALTER DATABASE   MOUNT...
```

Comment: ¿Cual es tu sistema operativo?

Comment: Windows 10 64 bits

Comment: En la lista de servicios, trata de hacerle restart al servicio del listener (`Oracle...Listener...`), y vuelve a probar. Si eso no funciona, hazle restart también a la instancia de base de datos (`OracleServiceXE`).

Comment: ese no es un problema de sql developer como tal, el problema es de tu oracle.

Comment: Sstan me puedes explicar como hacer lo que me comentas

Comment: Tienes que ir al Control Panel --> Administrative Tools --> Services. De esa ventana, busca los 2 servicios que te mencioné, le haces un clic de la derecha y seleccionas Restart.

Comment: @sstan ya los he reinicidado y me sigue dando el mismo error

Comment: No estoy seguro cual es tu error entonces. Revise este hilo a ver si algo allí te sirve: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23743910/ora-12528-tns-listener-all-appropriate-instances-are-blocking-new-connections.

Comment: @sstan haciendo todo lo que he visto en ese hilo solo consigo que el error cambie a  ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor.

Comment: Abre tu consola (command prompt - cmd.exe) y ejecuta las sentencias siguientes: 1) `set ORACLE_SID=XE`, y luego 2) `sqlplus / as sysdba`. ¿Qué resultado obtienes? Por favor captura el resultado en una imagen y agrégalo a la pregunta. Puedes ver en esta otra [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/122235/ora-12505-tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-sid-given-in-connect-descript) como le pedí a otra persona de hacer lo mismo para un problema diferente.

Comment: Ya están subidas la captura @sstan

Comment: Hmm, se vé normal. La prueba siguiente sería, una vez conectado con `sysdba` como lo hicistes, ejecuta las 2 sentencias siguientes: 1) `shutdown immediate`, y después 2) `startup`, y ver si algo raro aparece. Puedes compartir el resultado con una captura de pantalla.  Y finalmente, desde una consola diferente (cierra la ventana y abre una nueva) puedes intentar una conexión normal usando sqlplus: `sqlplus system@xe` y ver en que resulta. Otra captura de pantalla aquí sería ideal.

Comment: Hecho ya las he añadido @sstan, da errores distintos

Comment: Uy, sí. La instancia no logra arrancar. Para ver porqué, hay que examinar el log. Este se encuentra *ORACLE_HOME\diag\rdbms\xe\xe\trace\alert_xe.log*, donde *ORACLE_HOME* representa el directorio donde está instalado Oracle XE.  No sé cuan grande será el log, pero si quieres reducir su tamaño para que puedas compartirlo, puedes volver a conectarte con `sysdba` y ejecutar `shutdown immediate`. Luego puedes borrar el `alert_xe.log`. Y luego ejecutas `startup`, lo que debería crear un nuevo log file mas reducido con los detalles de interés.

Comment: Ya esta subido @sstan, gracias por todo

Comment: El log dice que no longra encontrar el archivo `C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\ORADATA\XE\CONTROL.DBF`. ¿Puedes confirmar si existe o no?  Si no existe, tal vez el problema sea relacionado a lo indicado [aquí](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3987640). Pero este problema es muy raro. Ese archivo no debería desaparecer así no mas. Yo reinstalaría Oracle XE.

Comment: El archivo no existe por mucho que reinstale oracle no lo crea. No hay una manera de sacarlo de Internet o de un ordenador donde esté correctamente configurado??

Comment: los DBF son archivos de la BD propiamente. Son archivos cuyo header incluy el ID de la instancia en tu instalación. No cabe usar "otro" de "alguna parte". Revisa el log generado al instalar, pues aparentemente hay una etapa que está fallando