# ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle, oracle-11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Buenas tardes, lo qué pasa es que tengo un error al intentar crear una conexión en SQLDeveloper "Estado: Fallo:Fallo de la prueba: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor"

Adjunto imagen de creando la conexión:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto imagen de mi TNSNAMES.ORA
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si me podrían ayudar de corazón muchas gracias.

Adjunto imagen del comando : set ORACLE_SID=XE
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto imagen del resultado del comando tnsping xe 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto imagen del segundo comando sqlplus system@XE 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto foto con el comando sqlplus system@XE después de colocar localhost
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto listener.ora
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Será que la instancia XE no está corriendo? ¿Cual es tu sistema operativo? Linux, Windows, ?

Comment: Tengo windows 10 y sobre la instancia de XE no tengo mucha idea, soy muy nuevo en oracle y no es que conozca demasiado.

Comment: Si vas a la ventana `Services` de Windows (Control Panel --> Administrative Tools --> Services), busca el servicio `OracleServiceXE` en la lista. ¿Está corriendo el servicio? Si no, arráncalo y vuelve a probar.

Comment: Si sr, si está corriendo (En Ejecución)

Comment: Abre tu consola (command prompt - cmd.exe) y ejecuta las sentencias siguientes: 1) `set ORACLE_SID=XE`, y luego 2) `sqlplus / as sysdba`. ¿Qué resultado obtienes? Tal vez sea necesario que captures el resultado en una imagen y la agregues a la pregunta.

Comment: Listo, ahí adjunto la imagen de la consola.

Comment: Eso está raro. Quiere decir que la instancia XE está corriendo correctamente.  Si puedes, has las pruebas siguientes, adjuntando los resultados a la pregunta. Prueba #1: en la consola, ejecuta `tnsping xe` y muestranos el resultado. Prueba #2: en la consola, intenta conectarte esta vez con la sentencia: `sqlplus system@XE`. Si funciona, debería pedirte la contraseña para el usuario `system`. Dejame saber si funciona la segunda prueba.

Comment: Bueno sr, ahí puse las dos imágenes con los dos comandos. En el segundo me aparece enter user-name y me deja copiar.

Comment: Algo no cuadra. La imagen de tu tnsnames.ora muestra que el host apunta a localhost. Pero cuando haces `tnsping xe`, allí dice que el host es `desktop-ppdd6sj`. Parece que tienes otro tnsnames.ora en alguna parte que no corresponde al que tu mostrastes. ¿Cual es el path donde se encuentra el tnsnames.ora?  ¿Y puedes, otra vez en la consola, mostrar cual es resultado de ejecutar `set path`?

Comment: Si es, lo que pasa es que lo cambie investigando y buscando solución pero con el desktop-ppdd6sj tampoco me daba me aparecía el mismo error.

Comment: C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN  Esa es la ruta de donde miro el tnsnames.ora

Comment: Abro ese tnsnames que aparece ahí y tiene el DESKTOP-PPDD6SJ en el host como lo dice el comando

Comment: Uy. Ahora es mas dificil interpretar el resultado de los tests. Lo ideal sería que cambiaras todo devuelta a localhost, que reinicies los servicios de ORacle (OracleServiceXE + Oracle...Listener...) y vuelvas a hacer las diferentes pruebas. Adicionalmente, verifica el archivo listener.ora, y asegurate que allí también se está usando localhost.

Comment: Bueno sr, ya cambie todo a localhost en el listener y tnsnames, reinicie los dos servicios, ejecute el comando tnsping xe y me aparece localhost, al poner el comando sqlplus system@XE me pide la contraseña de system, la coloco y me dice ORA-12541: TNS:no listener y después de esto me poner para enter user-name. Ahí adjunte foto del comando sqlplus system@XE

Comment: Este error es diferente. Dice que el listener no está corriendo. ¿Puedes verificar en la lista de servicios el service `ORacle... Listener...` y reinicializarlo otra vez de ser necesario? Luego vuelves a probar `sqlplus system@xe`

Comment: El (OracleXETNSListener) lo reinicie dos veces voy y coloco el comando sqlplus system@xe y me tira exactamente lo mismo.

Comment: Si haces un refresh (F5) en la ventana de los servicios, ¿en qué estado está el servicio del listener? Si no está corriendo es qué algo está mal con el listener. Si ese es el caso, agrega el listener.ora a la pregunta para ver que le ocurrió.

Comment: Ya hice el refresh a la ventana de servicio y aparece en ejecución el servicio, ahí te adjunte el listener.ora. ahí te señalo donde cambie de desktop-ppdd... a localhost.

Comment: Francamente, a estas alturas no tengo claro cual es el problema. En tu lugar, probablemente probaría lo que ya hicistes, o sea cambiar todos los localhost a `desktop-ppdd6sj` que asumo es el nombre de la máquina. Y luego reinicializar tanto el listener como el OracleServiceXE. Si se me ocurre otra cosa, dejaré un comentario.

Comment: Listo lo probaré y te comento y de todo corazón muchas gracias por invertir de tu tiempo en responderme, enserio muchas gracias por todo. Mi Dios te pague y espero  que tengas un feliz resto de día. MUCHAS GRACIAS!!!!

Answer (score 5):

Encontré la solución para mí aquí: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PIlY07mvrYA

Me pasaba exactamente lo mismo que a ti, espero que les sirva.

Lo que hice fue:

- Conectarme al system desde cmd
- Ejecutar: `SQL> show parameter local_listener` y me respondió que no tengo un listener como VALUE:

[image: respuesta del comando]

- Lo siguiente fue hacer un alter:

```
SQL> alter system set LOCAL_LISTENER='(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))' scope=both;

System altered.
```

- Y luego otro alter;

```
SQL> alter system register;
System altered.
```

- Para verificar que quedó correctamente volvemos a hacer un show:

```
SQL> show parameter local_listener
```

[image: respuesta al comando]

La variable fue modificada y eso solucionó mi error.